# Vectorize window.zoo over start= and end=

Tags: r, vectorization, zoo

I have input data that look like that (reduced to two time-series for the example).

```
library(zoo)
begin <- as.Date(c('2003-02-12', '2003-01-23'))
end <- as.Date(c('2003-10-02', '2003-08-01'))
x.Date <- as.Date("2003-01-01") + seq(1, 365, 8) - 1
data <- matrix(rnorm(length(x.Date)*2), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(r = NULL, col = c('a', 'b')))
```

I'm trying to write a function that, for each time-series (x[,i]), averages the values for a window defined by begin[i] and end[i].

```
fun <- function(data, begin, end, dates) {
  x <- zoo(data, dates)
  xSub <- window(x, start = begin, end = end)
  colMeans(xSub, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

The function above (or a slightly modified version) works if a single time-series is provided, but is not properly vectorized over `begin` and `end`. Any idea how I could make this work?

```
# Slightly modified version working for single time-series
fun2 <- function(data, begin, end, dates) {
  x <- zoo(data, dates)
  xSub <- window(x, start = begin, end = end)
  mean(xSub, na.rm = TRUE)
}

fun2(data[,1], begin[1], end[1], x.Date) # OK

fun(data, begin, end, x.Date) # Same window is used for both time-series
```

The function should reproduce the behaviour of this loop.

```
out <- c()
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  x <- zoo(data[,i], x.Date)
  xSub <- window(x, start = begin[i], end = end[i])
  out <- c(out, mean(xSub))  
}
```

Thanks,
Loïc

Comment: do you want to pass a vector of begin values, and a vector of end values, and have the function return a vector whose values are the result of pair-by-pair evaluations?

Comment: @J.Won. That's precisely what I'm trying to achieve. I edited the question to illustrate that.

Comment: Perhaps, see `mapply`: `mapply(function(j, b, e) fun2(data[, j], b, e, x.Date), seq_len(ncol(data)), begin, end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the zoo object to be used, convert it to a list of zoo objects and `Map` (or `mapply`) over it.

```
z <- zoo(data, x.Date)
Map(window, as.list(z), start = begin, end = end)
```

Note that the key is to use `as.list`, not `list`.

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` is probably the best way to do it.

```
fun <- function(data, begin, end, dates) {
  x <- zoo(data, dates)
  step1 <- mapply(window, start=begin, end=end, MoreArgs=list(x=x))
  sapply(step1, colMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was kind of my initial approach. Although, to work the `x` variable in the mapply call would need to be part of the variable over which `window` is vectorized. But it doesn't sound so easy to vectorize it over the right dimension of `x`.

Comment: We evaluate for each different pair of `begin`/`end`, but for only one value of `x`. That's why `x` is passed separately in the MoreArgs list.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer that really shows how a vectorized solution can do anything a for loop does.

```
fun <- function(data, begin, end, dates) {
  x <- zoo(data, dates)
  paircount <- 1:length(begin)
  sapply(paircount, function(i) mean(window(x[,i], start=begin[i], end=end[i]), na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that one, works well. Slightly edited.